# What is the glue stuff you use to seal a glass shower panel to the tub?

Tags: shower, bathtub, sealing

I've got a frameless shower enclosure (I think that's what it is called) and the transparent glue/seal between the glass and the tub is peeling off.  What is it? I'm guessing some kind of transparent silicone but my search-foo isn't working properly and I can't find it.

(I'm not talking about the hard plastic "sweep" that goes under the movable glass door.  I'm talking about a very thin bead of transparent stuff along the boundary between glass and tub - as shown by the obligatory hand drawn red marks on the image below.)

P.S. If you've got any tips on how to replace this stuff properly I would be happy to read them in your answer!

[image: Glass shower enclosure fixed panel showing the area where this glue is peeling off of]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use high-quality clear silicone caulk for showers(Mildew resistant).  You often get quality caulk at tile stores or GE makes a good one you can get from your local hardware or big box.  After the old caulk is removed clean with white vinegar. 
The trick to a good caulk bead on your shower is to make sure it is completely clean and dry.  Cut the caulk tube tip at a slight angle and only enough to fill the gap.  Don't cut the tip down too far as this just makes a mess putting out too much caulk.  Lay the bead of caulk at one go, a section at a time.   Move at a steady pace to a corner.  Wet your finger with alcohol, if using silicone,(use water if you choose latex caulk) and smooth the bead with light pressure.  Silicone is a little harder to work with than latex, but it lasts much longer.  Make sure you let it dry at least 24 hours before using shower.

Comment: I liked @JACK 's answer too but very much appreciate your tips on using alcohol for silicone caulk and vinegar to clean.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is clear silicone caulk. you want to peel off the old caulk, scrap the tile with a single edge razor blade to get all the old caulk off, clean with bleach to remove any trace of mildew and let dry. Then apply the caulk and let dry for 24 hours. The caulk can be bought at any home store or hardware. Here's a picture of a popular brand.
[image]

It also comes in a tube that doesn't need a caulking gun. Good luck.